# Generic Type with non-Generic Implementation

Tags: java, generics, interface

Recently I encountered the code like this: `List<Person> somevar = new ArrayList<>();`

I don't understand how the variable declared with specialized generic type `List<Person>` can be initialized with a non-generic type constructor ArrayList<>();

The latter code obviously works fine, but why? and how?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called `Diamond Operator`, and it's just a syntactic sugar to write less code. It's equivalent to:

```
List<Person> somevar = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

It's available since `Java/JDK 7`.

Comment: I'd just add my two cents by pointing out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html - it is part of the Java7 language enhancements, present since July 2011.

Answer (score 2):

It is called "The Diamond Operator". The reason you don't have to add a type parameter, is because it is **inferred** by the left-side variable you are assigning it too.

It is similar as with generic methods. Type inference was already working on these before Java 7:

This seems to be a good article about it:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html

Answer (score 0):

`new ArrayList<>;` is not a valid syntax.
A valid syntax would be `new ArrayList<>();` which is referred to as the "diamond notation". It is not non-generic: the compiler will deduce the type from the context.

non-Generic would be `new ArrayList();`

Comment: it was just typo, you are right, I forgot to append the constructor parentheses.

Comment: but wait.. what means "comiler will deduce" ?
so if I have a generic Interface Type<T> and I can create several implementation objects, why then compiler is not making a deduction though?, the thing is not "sugar" or what's happening.. I know it works.. but why? you are explicitly declaring the type as Interface generalized of Person objects and the ArrayList<>() objejct is definitely NOT implementing that interface.

I KNOW that it works.. just can't understand - Why.

Comment: It is explained in the link given by @JozefChocolacek http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html